# Exit from a function in C#

Tags: c#, exit

A basic question. I need to exit a function without throwing any exceptions. How do I do that in C#?

Comment: What about using Break; ? I do think you could have easily found this on google within seconds. Aside that this is probably a duplicate 2.

Comment: How do I use it? is it not just break;

Comment: no break will not exit from function. you can write break in loops. use return to exit. +1 Kamyar

Answer (score 33):

It's as simple as:

```
void Function()
{
    ...

    if(needToLeave)
        return;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't find the question to be that inane, really. I honestly can't remember when I learned of being able to just return from void, but it certainly wasn't from a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you. I agree this is real basics

Comment: Well I was just ruling out return since my function did not return any value;) Again i know I have to refresh my basics here..

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Maybe using `return;`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using "return;" I've always suggested a right logic.

In other words, you don't need to leave execution from some method: just use a conditional statement so if some boolean isn't true, that would mean some code mustn't be executed.

But I assume this is my opinion, and others prefer returning the control to the caller.

Additionally, you'd like to know exception-based flow control is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use the return or break keywords ...... But make sure nothing is after these statements as you may have unreachable code. Also having multiple exits in your code can make it difficult to maintain in the future

Answer (score -1):

you can put you code in a try catch block and do whatever you want to do in the finally block without worrying about the exception.

```
 try
        {
         //try something   
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //catch all exceptions and log on need basis
            //but do not throw the exception from here
        }
        finally
        {
            return "Test";
            //do what ever you want to do 
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

May be to Keep the catch block empty. Please explain your question

Comment: No matter what the problem is, an empty catch block is not the solution.