# How to terminate a method execution Midway in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to *exit* from a *method* when a certain condition is reached. The other lines of code should not be executes after exit `Condition` is reached. what is the best way for this I have tried to use `Environment.Exit(0)`, but it *causes problem in my logic*.

`Exit(0)` does not seem to work unless in a loop

Comment: There is the a _return_ statement last time I checked :-)

Comment: `Environment.Exit` terminates the *process*, it is **highly** unlikely this is what you want. As @Steve commented, the correct way would be to `return` from the method, something like `if (condition) return;` would suffice.

Comment: ..Or *throw exception* `throw new SomeException(...)` if something wrong has happened

Comment: Please post your code - maybe there's something about your scenario we're misunderstanding ?

Comment: Why do you state: "Exit(0) does not seem to work unless in a loop"? Exit terminates the process, in a loop or not. This is very confusing.

Comment: What error do you actually get from using Exit(0) in a loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exit from a function in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855991/exit-from-a-function-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6):

We have *two* possibilities: normal (`return`) and abnormal (`throw`) termination:

```
 public static int Factorial(int value) {
   // We can't compute factorial for negative and too large values
   if (value < 0 || value > 12)
     throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value)); // Abnormal termination

   if (value == 0)
     return 1;  // Normal termination: special case in which we know the answer

   ... 
 }
```

Comment: Good job for including throw. I did not think of that one at all.

Answer (score 2):

The "return" statement exits condition-blocks aswell as loops and methods.

```
public void myMethod(int a){
    if( 1 == a) {
      return;
    }
    // do something with a
}
```

Comment: No need for `else` - no code will be executed after `return` (except if it's in a `finally` block).

Comment: Well, it's an example... and the OP mentioned that his/her code should exit on specific condition only.

Comment: My point is, `if(1 == a) {return;} /* do something with a */` does exactly the same as `if(1 == a) {return;} else { /* do something with a */`}`, but with less code.

Answer (score 0):

As some people have already said before me, return is the way to go.
Here is an example where an if statement compares two integers and returns if they are equal:

```
public void isEqual(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
      Console.WriteLine("Integers are equal");
      return; //Return to executing the rest of the program.
    }
    else {
      Console.WriteLine("Integers are not equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: this is just wrong. "terminating" method and application / process is totally different. I did not downvote you but I'd suggest you to improve / delete your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I will remove that part then, having a long day

Comment: Sure, happens to all of us :)

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Actually no, correct answer is return; as already stated in the comments